# Converting 3d profiles to points in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, point, interpolation, line

I have created some 3d profiles using the Interpolate Line button (in ArcGIS 10.1). Which looks like:

[image]

I would like to convert these lines into points and in order to do that I am under the impression that I need to have a shapefile of these lines. I am not really sure how to do that and was wondering whether anyone could give me some pointers.

Also, do I have to create a new feature class and re-draw these lines?

If so is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create profile lines and use the [Profile Graph tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_a_profile_graph_from_digitized_features_of_a_surface/00q80000009p000000/) , the tool creates points along the line for you and saves them in the same location as your MXD's default Geodatabase in a folder called ProfileGraph Data.